# Mysql bigint, decimal(18,0) or char(10) for primary

Tags: mysql, char, decimal, myisam, bigint

For a huge myisam table (over 1B rows), i have 2 unique variable one of them has 18 numeric digits, the other has 10 latin chars.

Which one i should prefer for primary key?
If for numeric; decimal or bigint?

Non of them will not help me on select queries, so better to have unique key or still primary key usefull?

Answer (score 0):

Numeric is definitely better. I would say you should have your PK as A_I field. Because a number is smaller and with A_I it makes a sorted Primary Key index (faster to index).